# Foundation top-bar breaks when loading another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am currently building a small website using ruby on rails and foundation as the css framework. I implemented a top bar for navigation with 2 items being nested drop downs.

Here is the code of the top-bar that is inside my layout/application.html.erb:

```
<body>
    <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
            <li class="menu-text">Logo</li>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stats">Statistics</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/items">Items</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Infected items</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Detective items</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/guides">Guides</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Lore</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Beginner tutorial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mod rules</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Strategy guide</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How to be a good detective?</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>



        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

As shown in the following picture:

[image: Working top bar]

The code behaves as intended **until** I open the statistics page right next to home, as shown in this one:

[image: Broken top bar]

If I enter the stats page manually, I get no problems until I switch back to home. This happens anytime I click a link of the top bar that is not the same page that I currently am at.

I currently have no custom javascript or jQuery listeners implemented at all and I'm using a fresh foundation installation using foundation-rails.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it? Is it related to rails?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a conflict between foundation and turbolinks.

For anyone running into this kind of apparently random issues, I solved this by following the approach suggested here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2348-foundation-5-topbar-menu-not-responding-on-rails4